# How it works when assigning a pointer * to a pointer **?

Tags: c++

I am learning about pointers.
when i practice assigning pointer * by pointer ** then p_to_p = ptr but *p_to_p != *ptr.
Here is my practice code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
    
    int value = 100;
    int *ptr = &value;
    int **p_to_p = (int**)ptr;

    cout << p_to_p << "   " << ptr << endl; 
    cout << *p_to_p << "   " << *ptr << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Please explain how it works when assigning pointers * to pointers **.
Thank you very much!

Comment: the correct way to create a p_to_p is `int **p_to_p = &ptr;`

Comment: There's nothing to explain. This is "undefined behavior".

Comment: @MMD i know that but i'm trying to understand for clarification on this part

Comment: As an analogy, a pointer hold the address to your house.  A pointer-pointer holds the address to your local post office, and that local post office holds an address to your house.

Comment: Thanks for the great advices!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> int **p_to_p = (int**)ptr;
> ```

Here, you reinterpret the value of `ptr` as a `int**`. All object pointers can be reinterpreted as pointers of other types, but you generally may not indirect through such reinterpreted poiters except for rare cases.

> ```
> *p_to_p
> ```

This is not such exceptional case. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

```
int **p_to_p = (int**)ptr;
```

is a typecast. A reinterpret one.

What you probably want is the same you did on the line before:

```
int **p_to_p = &ptr;
```

Taking the address of a pointer gives you a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

By declaring a variable as int **, you are defining a pointer to an integer pointer. So you should assign the address of the integer pointer to it. You can do this way:

```
int **p_to_p = &ptr;
cout << **p_to_p << endl;
```